# What is this て-form at the end of a sentence: 「まったく可愛くねー起こし方しやがって！」

Tags: て-form, spoken-language

That comes from Ranma 1/2. Ranma asked Akane to wake up him up, and she did that by throwing water on him.
He then said:

> 何しやがるんだ！
>   *What the hell are ya doing!*

When she left, he then thought out loud

> くそー　アカネの奴。　まったく可愛くねー　起こし方しやがって！
>   *That damn Akane, waking me up in the uncutest way ever!*

I know "yagaru" is an unpositive version of "morau, kureru".

Yet, I'd instead say

> おい、何しやがる｜しやがった！
>   ったくアカネの奴、全然可愛くねえ起こし方しやがった。

People said this "tte" makes the sentence more emotive. Can you guys explain this further, any give more examples of how to use it?

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> まったく可愛くねー　起こし方しやがっ**て**！

In colloquial speech, the te-form of a verb at the end of a sentence can express 非難 (reproach/criticism/condemnation) or 不満 (complaint/dissatisfaction).

Examples:

> 「太郎ったら、また脱いだものほったらかしにし**て**！」
>   「もう、ケンカばっかりし**て**！いいかげんにしなさい！」
>   「どいつもこいつも、俺をバカにしやがっ**て**！」

<sub>As a side note, the て-form at the end of a sentence can also express 命令/依頼(command/request), 釈明(explanation), 感嘆(exclamation), etc.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is merely a omitted form of some sort of longer sentence like:

○○（し）やがって（、嫌いだ・困る。）<-omitted

---

Added:

し is the 連用形 of する，て can be understood as a 接続助詞。