# Question concerning 〜やがる / Imperative in "Slang"

Tags: grammar, expressions

I've come across these expressions in all sorts of anime, manga and light novels and now I am wondering behind the "mechanics" of it...

> 「勝手に言**ってろ**」「ほざい**てろ**」「食らい**やがれ**」

In these cases the imperative is used; these expressions are usually similar to the English 'Shut up', 'Take that', etc.

However in cases like:

> 「**ふざけやがって**」

I am not sure what is implied by that...

I get the meaning of what is said however I am unsure about its grammatical form.
Can it be understood as 「っている」 just with 「いる」 being left out?

What exactly does this 「〜て」 mean if nothing follows here?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50420/9831