# how does te form actually work at the end of sentence?

Tags: grammar, て-form

Now i dont mean the request, like with ください、くれ etc omitted
currently, i have big problems with this, the only conclusion i came to is, there is probably something omitted at the end??
for example

何が危ない考えだ! 変人扱いしやが**って** (**ひどい**)

there it feels like the person is really angry and omits something like **ひどい**

My translation:
"What is an dangerous thought?! they dare to treat me like a weirdo. **thats cruel**!"

another example:

人に化けて潜んでるって聞いたことあるし、案外近くにいたりし**て**な (**そんなわけないけどね**)
there it feels like the person is joking, and feels like there is something like **そんなわけないけどね**  omitted?

My translation:
i heard that they turn themselves into people and then hide, so they can unexpectedly be somewhere near (**but that doesnt make much sense does it?**)

But there are also usages of て form which i dont understand in the slightest like:

簡単なよう**で**ね, 実際は難しい。-Since there is also continuation, maybe there is something omitted in middle? but i dont think so, there it feels like the で means something like けど but, if thats so, why wouldnt the person use exactly that?

And i also noticed, that te form is really overused in songs, my conclusion again is that it maybe helps with the flow of the song? if they can chain actions and stuff on each other??

Is my understanding correct?
And can someone thoroughly explain this to me?
I have seen many threads on this, but i dont really think it actually solves my problem

Comment: Related: [What is this て-form at the end of a sentence: 「まったく可愛くねー起こし方しやがって！」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50420/43676)

Comment: Thanks, half of my problem solved.

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of 〜たりして?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5705/43676)

Comment: Thanks, And what about the 簡単なようでね, 実際は難しい?  I wasnt really able to find anything that helps me with it